# How to publish my documents folder in remoteapp

Tags: windows, server, remoteapp

I'm publishing Documents folder to every user in Windows Server 2012, I'm using this code to publish the folder:

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe %UserProfile%\My Documents

And it works, but I want to "hide" the quick access and exclude to explore any another drive or folder to show , just see Documents windows, I know it's possible, but I don't find the right option to hide it...

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe %UserProfile%\My Documents

Answer (score 0):

Start a rooted Explorer:

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,/root,%UserProfile%\My Documents
```

And My Documents might not be the correct name of the folder, you should use the shell protocol:

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,/root,shell:personal
```

This will not prevent the user from viewing other folders in another Explorer window.

Comment: both options works same, but it's not what I'm looking for, the explorer in the left panel (This PC, hard drives, downloads, videos, etc) still there, I want to hide that panel....

Comment: Windows XP was the last version where you could control that folder panel from the command-line. It is called the Navigation Pane in newer versions and you cannot control it from the command line AFAIK.